# Put language index into URL Multilanguage CodeIgniter site

Tags: php, internationalization, codeigniter-3

My site is created in three languages https://anto-nguyen.com.

It works well to translate from one language to another one.
But.. I can't put the language indication into the URL.
I looked through all questions and answers that I could find here and have tried to use them, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work..

I use Controller LangSwitch

```
class LangSwitch extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }    
    function switchLang($language = "") {

        $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);
        
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }

}
```

The language is called by following code integrated into menu

```
<div>
    <?= anchor(base_url("langSwitch/switchLang/english"), 'En'); ?>
    <?= anchor(base_url("langSwitch/switchLang/french"), 'Fr'); ?>
    <?= anchor(base_url("langSwitch/switchLang/russian"), 'Ру'); ?> 
</div>
```

My .htaccess lookes like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeigniter/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And seems to be modified, but all suggestions I found doesn't work

Could you help me what to do that my link will appeared as /mysite/fr /mysite/en /mysite/ru?

All translation are in the folders language/english language/french language/russian

Mayby to change something in routes?

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
$route['work'] = 'work/index'; //the URL 'work' will redirect to 'work/index'
$route['work/(:any)_(:num)'] = 'work/article/$2';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['(:any)'] = 'site/$1';
```

Comment: because you have added `redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Comment: so it will redirect to back, that's why your site url not indicating the language in url

Comment: Thank you Eliot, you mean that I need to delete this line?
I tried to delete it, but in this case the redirection doesn't work after calling the other language

Comment: yes, so you can solve it

Comment: No.. it doesn't work

Comment: Why don't you use ready-made, working solutions anymore? e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672833/modular-codeigniter-language-routing